# Export to PDF file and use in latex, weird behaviour from using Acrobat

Tags: latex, pdf-format

I have put all files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oeiow6vqk2os6fh/Pictures.zip?dl=0).

All pictures are Exported from Mathematica 10.0.1 X64 (win7) using `Export["filename.pdf",plotobject]`.

I first complied the latex file, and got `test.pdf`, which looks good.

Then I use Adobe Acrobat to extract page 2 and page 3, `test_page2_3.pdf`.
There is a problem.

Look from `test.pdf`
[image]
Look from `test_page2_3.pdf`
[image]

The graph has CHANGED!
phi7 becomes phi3????
also the x-axis has changed!!!

If I use

```
\includepdf[pages={2-3},delta=0mm 0mm]{test.pdf}
```

to re latex it. The output PDF file is ok.

I am not sure if this is a Mathematica problem or a latex problem. But I just though someone might have the same experience?

ONLY occur in TWO graphs. Dont know why.

Comment: Are you able to provide a complete (self-contained) minimal example that replicates this problem?

Comment: Regrettably, i could not. However, I did upload all PDF files (produced by MMA) considered. I  believe the problem lies in those PDF files, (in particular, phi7.pdf and phi8.pdf)?